# Finding unique morphism in a diagram of exact sequences such the whole diagram commute.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $$\begin{array}{c}
 0 & \xrightarrow{} &M' & \xrightarrow{i} & M & \xrightarrow{p} & M'' \\
 & &  & & \downarrow{g}  & & \downarrow{h}\\
0 & \xrightarrow{} &N' & \xrightarrow{j} & N & \xrightarrow{k} & N''  \\
\end{array}$$

be a commutative diagram ,$hp=kg$, in some abelian category like modules or abelian groups where both rows are exact, then prove there is an unique morphism $f:M' \to N'$ such $gi=jf$. My attemp to prove this was by diagram chasing trying to emulate **proposition 2.70 of Rotmans´s Homological Algebra**. My natural candidate for $f:M' \to N'$ is as $f:=j^{-1}gi$ where $j^{-1}:N \to N'$ is the preimage of $j$ but there may be some $n \in N$ such $n \notin Im(j)$ so how I can properly define this $f$?

Comment: The image of $j$ is the kernel of $k$, and the image of $g\circ i$ is contained in the kernel of $k$?

Comment: That´s right beacuse the commutative of the right square. So candidate for$f$ is right? @CharlieFrohman

Comment: The candidate for $f$ is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By diagram chasing: Let $m'\in M'$, then $i(m')\in \ker(p)$ by exactness, so we have
$$
k(gi(m')) = h(pi(m')) = h(0) = 0
$$
so $gi(m')\in \ker(k)=j(N')$, then there exists $n'\in N'$ such that $gi(m')=j(n')$. Define $f(m')=n'$. This is well defined, because if $gi(m')=j(n'')$ for some $n''\in N'$ then $j(n')=j(n'')$, but by exactness, $j$ is injective, thus $n'=n''$.

Now note that
$$
gi(m') = j(n') = jf(m')
$$
and thus the diagram is commutative.

Finally, let $f':M'\to N'$ be another morphism such that the diagram is commutative. Note that
$$
 jf = gi = jf',
$$
but $j$ is a monomorphism, so $jf=jf'$ implies that $f=f'$.